# STM32F103C8T6 3.3v pin max output

Tags: stm32f103c8t6

Im using STM32F103C8T6 with sl4432 as small radio beacon. It's working fine, but range much shorter than suppose to be. Sl4432 require max 85 mAh for 20dbm transmit, but how much STM32F103C8T6 3.3v pin can give at max? I can't find that info in datasheet and it's not GPIO pin anyway.

---

To be more specific, I power up STM32F103C8T6 from blue circle. And power up my sl4432 from green circle.
[[image: pinout]]

[image: here what board is that]

Comment: Are you connecting your Sl4432's power supply pin to a GPIO output from your STM32?

Comment: Are you talking about the microcontroller's VDD pins?  Those consume current, they do not supply it.  The current comes from your power supply.  Do you have the facilities to measure the output power from your board?  At those frequencies, board design and component choice is going to have a critical effect on whether the chip develops the power that's promised.

Comment: I will upload image... Sec.

Comment: The actual subject of your question is not the MCU but an unidentified board containing it.  You will need to obtain the specifications from the manufacturer and use the lesser of that or the upstream power source's capability.  Or provide the exact identification of the regulator used on the board.  **It's fairly unlikely that this is the source of your problem**.  That's more likely to be insufficient point-of-load capacitors, misconfiguration of the radio, receiver problems, a noisy environment (or noisy receiver power), poorly chosen radio scheme bad antennas or unrealistic expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3V3 pin in your dev board is not an actual MCU pin but the output of an onboard 3.3V linear regulator. Also, both your green and blue pins are internally connected, so the max current you can source out of that pin is the max current your power source can provide.

I would recommend removing the onboard LDO if you are providing the 3.3V externally.

You can check out the schematic at the stm32duino wiki for the Blue Pill:

https://wiki.stm32duino.com/index.php?title=Blue_Pill

Answer (score 0):

The STM32F103 series does not contain a 3.3V regulator.

If you're referring to a pin labelled "3.3V" on a development board, this pin is probably fed by a linear regulator on the board. You will need to refer to the specifications on that part for information on its current capacity.

Answer (score -1):

It is the BluePill. This 3.3V is actually a part of the SWD programming port and if is used to source the current it takes it from the small LDO on board. Use 5V port with a proper LDO.

Comment: Only a small fraction of the world's SOT23-5 regulators would be unable to supply 85 mA in addition to the current required by an STM32.  100 mA and below ratings do exist in this package, but they're not the common ones.  This isn't like the on-chip regulator of an Arduino derivative's USB interface chip which can only spare a few tens of milliamps.

Comment: Adding some capacitors at the radio (if they don't already exist on its board) might not be a bad idea.  But the real problem is probably something else.

Comment: @ChrisStratton 5V is connected directly to the USB VDD. He will need to use his own LDO + capacitors.

Comment: No, because the regulator feeding the 3v3 pin he is presently using probably has sufficient capacity.  That this was a power problem at all was only ever a wild guess; if it is power related (and it probably isn't) then explanation is more likely lack of capacitance at the point of load, not the regulator.

Comment: @P__J__ - Hi, As I understand the OP's connections, they claim to be supplying power to the SWD port. The power pin on that connector (circled in blue by the OP) is already on the 3.3V net. The 3.3V pin (circled in green by the OP) which is supplying the Si4462 radio is *also* on the 3.3V net. Therefore the LDO (5V in, 3.3V out) isn't involved at all, is it? [Here is the Blue Pill STM32F103C8 schematic](https://wiki.stm32duino.com/images/c/c1/Vcc-gnd.com-STM32F103C8-schematic.pdf) to confirm my statement. Do you agree that it shows any concerns about the on-board LDO are a red herring? Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisStratton no. It does not matter if the LDO is capable or not. Is is **always** wrong to supply external this kind of devices from the uC supply circuit.

Comment: @SamGibson No. I think he powers the BP using the USB. He just should not power another devices from the uC branch.

Comment: -1, no it is not "always wrong" to supply peripherals from a controller board.  It is *sometimes* wrong for *some* peripherals, especially power hungry or grungy ones such as motors.  This is not in that category.  Engineering is about applying actual knowledge of these details, not about claims unsupported in the context where they are made.

Comment: I'm powering it NOT from usb. I showed that on picture. As far as 3.3v pin going directly from powering pin then it's not power related. Thanks all for helping to find out it.

Comment: @Chrisstratton I afraid it is always wrong. Only the damage done may be less or more severe. Thanks for the DV. Top man!

Comment: As any engineer will explain to you, systems have ratings so that you know what you can ask them to do *without risking damage*.  If we were to follow your irrational argument, even lighting a single small LED from a board would be forbidden.  Everyone knows it isn't.  Think this through and you'll come to the rational realization that you must consider the proposed load vs. the proposed controller board to find out if it is appropriate.  Blanket statements such as you have made which givie no consideration to the actual facts are not defensible.

Comment: @ChrisStratton even more - analogue and digital part of the uC power should be separated as well. Every rapid change of the current flown in the uC power circuit (even if it is only 20mA) generates some noise which degrades parameters of the uC peripherals - for example ADC. So the rule of thumb - uC power separate from the other devices power. If you power the devece from the uC power - you intentionally degrade its quality. It is done for the simplicity or cost reasons, but not because it is correct. And people reading it, should know it. Then we have question like : why by ADC is so noisy?